# Rotate image in jquery and save rotate image in jquery

Tags: jquery-ui

In my application I have some images and I want to rotate them and then save the rotated images.

I have rotated the images successfully but I could not save them.

Is It possible in jQuery to save the images? Does anyone know how to do it?

Comment: You can not do that on the client side. You would have to do something server side like with PHP for instance.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagerotate.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the image is a simple image on the page (an img tag) that you rotate using the CSS3 transform rotate property I don't think there's a way to save the image as a rotated image file. But you could save the value of the CSS rotate property and then use it the next time someone views the page.

If you need to save the rotated image as a file, I'd suggest that you use HTML Canvas to rotate the image and the save the content of the canvas to a file:

http://creativejs.com/2012/01/day-10-drawing-rotated-images-into-canvas/