# How rotate image and save it from JSP/Servlet page

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, jsp, servlets

I was able to successfully use JQueryRotate to rotate my images in a JSP page.
However, the user now wants to have the ability to save the rotated image.

But from what I've gathered so far, it seems that it's not possible to do this client side. So I probably have to re-start from scratch.

Is it possible to do a rotate image with saving capability for images rendered in a JSP/Servlet?  If yes, how?

EDIT: By the way, HTML5 is out of the questions because my requirement is to still support IE9.

Comment: What you mean is to save an image rendered in a browser after being rotated? As jpg or png or whatelse?

Comment: Yes. Saving it as png is fine.  Any ideas?

Comment: Seems to be a dup. of http://stackoverflow.com/q/16318629/3183018

Comment: Well, as @user3183018 pointed there is an answer and the answer is no. Predictable - the picture is on the client side. I've just wanted to be sure I understood the question well and didn't miss something.

Comment: @ThrashBean: From the answer I linked it seems possible if HTML5 canvas can be used.

Comment: As the answer says is possible to save the canvas, how you will retrieve the image is other issue. Realy, I don't think you can save modified image from the browser.

Comment: How do Facebook or other image sharing websites do it then?

Comment: By the way, HTML5 is out of the questions because my requirement is to still support IE9. I have updated my OP.

Comment: @ThrashBean: Sorry, misunderstood. Thought he wanted to enable the user to save the modified image on the client side. E.g. right clicking canvas container, then save.

Answer (score 0):

Well, just to sumarize. Using non-HTML5 browsers - no way to save the modified on the client side picture. In a modern browser - you could try to save a canvas containing the image. Also you could keep track of the css trasformation and, on demand, render trasformed image but this is server side and just will show rotated image, not save it. Other thing you could do is send the transformed image to the server when the user ask for saving operation, rotate/transform the image using image manipulation software/library on the server side and send the new image back to the client. This could work, for example php has some image libraries. BTW, some social sites share images but, I think, all the transformation if any (crop, cut, resize, rotate...) is made on the server, when the user upload the image and it is saved on the server. BTW (2) a time ago in a J2EE application we had to do something like this because of user requirement - save an image rendered in a browser to the client machine. Will try to rescue the idea and if there is something interesting will post it.

**EDITED**
Here is some code we made a time ago for saving screen captures:

```
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class Screenshot {

    public Screenshot() {
    }

    public static void imageCapture(int left, int top, int width, int height, String outFileName, String imgFormat) {
        if (!outFileName.toUpperCase().endsWith(imgFormat)) {
            outFileName += "." + imgFormat;
        }
        try {
            Robot robot = new Robot();
            BufferedImage bi = robot.createScreenCapture(new Rectangle(left, top, width, height));
            ImageIO.write(bi, imgFormat, new File(outFileName));
        }
        catch (AWTException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void imageCapture(int left, int top, int width, int height, OutputStream outStream, String imgFormat) {
        try {
            Robot robot = new Robot();
            BufferedImage bi = robot.createScreenCapture(new Rectangle(left, top, width, height));
            ImageIO.write(bi, imgFormat, outStream);
        }
        catch (AWTException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

As you see we used java.awt. Set full file path or already prepared OutputStream to the file you want to write and then send back to the browser the image file. This approach has a disadvantage - if you have scroll, the parte out of the window (let say "scrolled out") will no be captured. Well in fact it has many disadvantages but that's all I have and you can make some research. Hope this helps.